# Map object with array in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using **Vue Select Image** for multi selecting images. **Vue Select Image** expects the array to be with the following keys

```js
[{
  id: '1',
  src: 'https://unsplash.it/200?random',
  alt: 'Alt Image 1'
}, {
  id: '2',
  src: 'https://unsplash.it/200?random',
  alt: 'Alt Image 2'
}]
```

And my api route gives the object with following keys:

```js
(2)[{…}, {…}]
0:
  created_at: "2019-07-26 07:44:56"
id: 3
name: null
path: "img/d1ef5a9c54ee32df12c213b1491e1636.jpg"
thumb: "img/thumb_d1ef5a9c54ee32df12c213b1491e1636.jpg"
updated_at: "2019-07-26 07:44:56"
```

Below is my code snippet:

```js
import VueSelectImage from "vue-select-image";
import "vue-select-image/dist/vue-select-image.css";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dataImages: [{
        id: "",
        src: "",
        alt: ""
      }]
    },
    selected: {},
      initialLoad() {
        axios.get("api/gallery").then(response => {
          this.dataImages = Object.keys(response.data.data).map(function(key) {
            return [Number(key), response.data.data[key]];
          });
          // console.log(response.data.data);
        });
      },
      components: {
        VueSelectImage
      },
  };
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
  <vue-select-image :dataImages="dataImages" @onselectimage="selected"></vue-select-image>
  </div>
</template>
```

The above code maps object with array with its own keys. And displays 2 circle as there are 2 data receiving from api. Clicking on them gives the following error:

> Error in event handler for "onselectimage": "TypeError: fns.apply is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map through array of objects you get from API, it returns new array with objects with desired fields.

```
axios.get("api/gallery").then(response => {
  this.dataImages = response.data.data.map((obj, index) => {
    return {
      id: obj.id,
      src: obj.path,
      alt: `Alt image ${index}`
    };
  });
});
```